# Error when trying to install mysql-server

Tags: raspbian, apt, raspbian-jessie, mysql

I'm trying to install mysql-server package using `sudo apt-get install mysql-server` on my Raspberry Pi (Raspbian Jessie), but I encounter the following error :

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.5_5.5.44-0+deb8u1_armhf.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
[...]
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.5_5.5.44-0+deb8u1_armhf.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Then I did `sudo apt-get remove mysql-server` + `sudo apt-get autoremove`. I tried to rerun `sudo apt-get install mysql-server` but got the same error.

So I tried `sudo apt-get clean` and `sudo apt-get autoclean` but still have the same error when trying to install mysql-server.

Does somebody encounter the same problem and found a solution ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

Good Afternoon. English is not my native language so please be patient.

I think your problem is with `dpkg` and not with MySql.

Try this: `sudo apt-get -f install`

And  then: `sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get autoremove`

For last the *classic*: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

That will fix `dpkg`. If `-f install` doesn't work try this:

`sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Hope this answer helps.